# How to defer form input binding until user clicks the submit button?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wanted to make a two-way data binding on my form input in Vue.js 2.3. However, I cannot use the `v-model` directive, because I want the data to be updated only on clicking the submit button. Meanwhile, the input value may be updated from another Vue method, so it should be bound to the data property `text`. I made up something like this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz19u340/):

```html
<div id="demo">
  <input :value="text" ref="input">
  <button @click="update">OK</button>
  <p id="result">{{text}}</p>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      text: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update: function () {
        this.text = this.$refs.input.value;
    }
  }
});
```

It works, but it does not scale well when there are more inputs. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this, without using $refs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an object and bind its properties to the inputs. Then, in your `update` method, you can copy the properties over to another object for display purposes. Then, you can set a deep watcher to update the values for the inputs whenever that object changes. You'll need to use `this.$set` when copying the properties so that the change will register with Vue.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      inputVals: {
        text: '',
        number: 0
      },
      displayVals: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.copyObject(this.displayVals, this.inputVals);
    },
    copyObject(toSet, toGet) {
      Object.keys(toGet).forEach((key) => {
        this.$set(toSet, key, toGet[key]);
      });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    displayVals: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.copyObject(this.inputVals, this.displayVals);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="inputVals.text">
  <input v-model="inputVals.number">
  <button @click="update">OK</button>
  <input v-for="val, key in displayVals" v-model="displayVals[key]">
</div>
```

If you're using ES2015, you can copy objects directly, so this isn't as verbose:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      inputVals: { text: '', number: 0 },
      displayVals: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.displayVals = {...this.inputVals};
    },
  },
  watch: {
    displayVals: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.inputVals = {...this.displayVals};
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="inputVals.text">
  <input v-model="inputVals.number">
  <button @click="update">OK</button>
  <input v-for="val, key in displayVals" v-model="displayVals[key]">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same question as with @DecadeMoon: what if I want to change the `displayVals` from another method? The input fields will not automatically update. How to bind `displayVals` to `inputVals` with scale?

Comment: Do you mean you want to permanently bind `displayVals` to `inputVals` after calling `update`?

Comment: I want the "source of truth" to be `displayVals` and I want to modify it not only by submitting the form, but also from other methods. But then I want the updated `displayVals` to be automatically shown in inputs, and user can edit them and only after clicking the submit button they should be updated. This would be a simple use case for `v-model` if values were updated on each keystroke, which is not the case in my situation.

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe you could update your question to be clear about that requirement?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. However, this is more verbose than using `$refs`. I think there should be a modifier like `v-model.submit`, which will update the value only on form submit (like `v-model.lazy` does on  change).

Answer (score 1):

You can use two separate data properties, one for the `<input>`'s value, the other for the committed value after the OK button is clicked.

```html
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="editText">
  <button @click="update">OK</button>
  <p id="result">{{text}}</p>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      editText: '',
      text: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update: function () {
      this.text = this.editText;
    }
  }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz19u340/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but then if I want to change the `text` value from another method, the input field will not update. How to bind `text` to `editText`?

Comment: Use a watcher to watch for changes to `text` and to set `editText` to the new value of `text`.

Comment: And what if I have 10s of inputs? This is much more boilerplate than using `$refs`. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: You're still going to need two data properties for each input field. Have an array of items where each item is an object with two properties: `editText` and `text`.

Answer (score 1):

With a slightly different approach than the other answers I think you can achieve something that is easily scalable.

This is a first pass, but using components, you could build your own input elements that submitted precisely when you wanted. Here is an example of an input element that works like a regular input element when it is outside of a `t-form` component, but only updates `v-model` on `submit` when inside a `t-form`.

```
Vue.component("t-input", {
  props:["value"],
  template:`
    <input type="text" v-model="internalValue" @input="onInput">
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      internalValue: this.value,
      wrapped: false
    }
  },
  watch:{
    value(newVal){
      this.internalValue = newVal
    }
  },
  methods:{
    update(){
      this.$emit('input', this.internalValue)
    },
    onInput(){
      if (!this.wrapped)
        this.$emit('input', this.internalValue)
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    if(this.$parent.isTriggeredForm){
      this.$parent.register(this)
      this.wrapped = true      
    }
  }
})
```

Here is an example of `t-form`.

```
Vue.component("t-form",{
  template:`
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <slot></slot>
    </form>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      isTriggeredForm: true,
      inputs:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    submit(){
      for(let input of this.inputs)
        input.update()
    },
    register(input){
      this.inputs.push(input)
    }
  }
})
```

Having those in place, your job becomes very simple.

```
<t-form>
  <t-input v-model="text"></t-input><br>
  <t-input v-model="text2"></t-input><br>
  <t-input v-model="text3"></t-input><br>
  <t-input v-model="text4"></t-input><br>
  <button>Submit</button>
</t-form>
```

This template will only update the bound expressions when the button is clicked. You can have as many `t-inputs` as you want.

Here is a working example. I included `t-input` elements both inside and outside the form so you can see that inside the form, the model is only updated on submit, and outside the form the elements work like a typical input.

```js
console.clear()
//
Vue.component("t-input", {
  props: ["value"],
  template: `
    <input type="text" v-model="internalValue" @input="onInput">
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      internalValue: this.value,
      wrapped: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(newVal) {
      this.internalValue = newVal
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.$emit('input', this.internalValue)
    },
    onInput() {
      if (!this.wrapped)
        this.$emit('input', this.internalValue)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.$parent.isTriggeredForm) {
      this.$parent.register(this)
      this.wrapped = true
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("t-form", {
  template: `
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <slot></slot>
    </form>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      isTriggeredForm: true,
      inputs: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      for (let input of this.inputs)
        input.update()
    },
    register(input) {
      this.inputs.push(input)
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "bob",
    text2: "mary",
    text3: "jane",
    text4: "billy"
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <t-form>
    <t-input v-model="text"></t-input><br>
    <t-input v-model="text2"></t-input><br>
    <t-input v-model="text3"></t-input><br>
    <t-input v-model="text4"></t-input><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </t-form>
  Non-wrapped:
  <t-input v-model="text"></t-input>
  <h4>Data</h4>
  {{$data}}
  <h4>Update Data</h4>
  <button type="button" @click="text='jerome'">Change Text</button>
</div>
```